# Problema con las tildes en BD Y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

No se porque me ha aparecido este error de repente y es que las tildes y las ñ sale con un símbolo extraño, he probado a utilizar ut8_encode que funciona visualmente pero en la base de datos no se guarda correctamente.
EJ:
Animales Fantásticos , en la página se ve bien pero en la BD se guarda así: Animales FantÃ¡sticos
No se como solucionar este problema porque ha aparecido de repente.
El Cotejamiento de mi bd y tablas es : utf8_general_ci
De esta forma me conecto:

```
public function db_connect()
        {
            $conn = mysqli_connect(LOCALHOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error()); 
            return $conn;
            

        }
        
        //Function to Select Database
        public function db_select($conn)
        {
            $db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn, DBNAME) or die(mysqli_error());
            return $db_select;
        }
```

Al final gracias al compañero funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
public function db_connect()
        {
            $conn = mysqli_connect(LOCALHOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error()); 
            $conn->set_charset("utf8");
            return $conn;
            
        }``
```

Comment: Me dices si te funciono la respuesta que te comente

Comment: @BetaM perdón pero no encuentro el error, puedes decirme donde esta y de esa forma corregirlo :)

Comment: @BetaM es cierto, muchas gracias

Comment: El otro post , no se como aplicarlo correctamente , he comprobado el header y lo tengo con utf-8, los archivos igual,he probado a poner esto:$conn = mysqli_connect(LOCALHOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error()); 
   return $conn;
   $conn->set_charset("utf8");
   $consulta = mysqli_query("SET NAMES UTF-8");Tampoco funciona

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto una consulta para eso, algo asi

```
$consulta = mysqli_query("SET NAMES UTF-8");
```

Asi todos los caracteres que se introduzcan ya deberían entrar bien

Answer (score 0):

Proba con y ya actualizas tu versión de php.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $conn->set_charset("utf8");

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con actualizar?

Comment: Me ha funcionado , he tenido que adaptarlo , gracias.